# Inject javascript using chrome extension...it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i'm trying to make a chrome extension that inject some js code into a page when it's load.
This is the code:

```js
//now create our observer and get our target element
var observer = new MutationObserver(fnHandler),
        elTarget = document.querySelector(".ng-binding"),
        objConfig = {
            childList: true,
            subtree : true,
            attributes: false, 
            characterData : false
        };

//then actually do some observing
observer.observe(elTarget, objConfig);

function fnHandler () {
    alert("DETECTED_VARIATION");
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector(".ng-binding").appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
}
```

```html
<div class="ng-binding">Observed div</div>
<button>Insert div</button>
```

LINK JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/drLrd9w5/1/

I want inject the js code in the page using my chrome extension and get the same result of jsfiddle page...
I mean: 
1) I open the website that use the html code i wrote earlier
2) The extension i made inject the javascript code i wrote earlier
3) I get the some results of jsfiddle...

I tried use some chrome extension on the Google Chrome Store (such as this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija ) but it doesn't work, too :(
What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your manifest.json file as well please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending the dependency of the js file into the body of the html page.

Using jquery:

```
$(document.body).append('<script src="' + chrome.extension.getURL(fileName) + '"></script>');
```